# MVVM - Share encapsulated model with other VMs

Tags: windows-phone-8, mvvm, parent-child, messaging

In my Windows Phone App there's a simple hierarchical model consisting of a class containing a collection of other domain objects.

In my xaml i have declared an ItemsContainer control that renders the items in the above mentioned collection as simple rectangles.

Now, at the VM level i have a structure that resembles my model with a parent VM having a collection of children VMs. Each child-VM encapsulates its own model.

Whenever the user taps the view bound to a child-VM a method of the parent-model object should be invoked taking the relevant child-model as parameter. This will in turn change some internal state that will be reflected (possibly) on all the child-views (not just the tapped one).

SO... given that i'm using the MVVM Light framework my current implementation is as follows:

- Child-VM exposes a command
- The command Execute method will use the messenger to notify the parent-VM of the tap event. The message (GenericMessage class) content will be the domain object encapsulated by the VM
- The parent-VM executes the method of the parent-model using the message content as parameter
- If the operation succeeds the parent-VM sends a new message to inform child-VMs of this fact. Once again the message content is the model object used as parameter in the method that was just invoked
- Child-VMs raise a couple of PropertyChanged events that, finally, will update the bound views

It works but i fill it's a bit cumbersome. The thing that bugs me the most is the fact that when a child-view is tapped the associated VM will broadcast its encapsulated model object. Do you feel that there would be a better way of implementing such a system?

Thanks in advance for your precious help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not just put the command on the parent viewmodel and pass the child viewmodel as the command parameter?

The parent view model can then just call methods on the child viewmodels to update them. I'm not sure I see the need for all these messages?

Comment: I see two problems: 1) how can i bind to the parent command from xaml  without hacks (inside the ItemTemplate of an ItemsContainer) - 2) the command of the parent-VM has to access the model that is encapsulated by the child-VM to do it's stuff, i don't think this should happen

Comment: 1) You can use RelativeSource, or ElementName etc. I do it all the time to reference, say an ItemsControl from inside an item. If you really hate this, then just pass the command to the child VM in the constructor, and it can expose it directly. 2) Can't the child VM expose a method that does whatever manipulations are needed? It's difficult to comment without knowing exactly what you're doing.

Comment: I'll provide more info: parent is a Map, children are Locations - when a location is tapped the command will change CurrentLocation property of the Map but only if the method Map.CanMoveTo(Location) returns true. That's why i need to get the encapsulated Location from the LocationViewModel

Comment: OK, this definitely sounds like something the parent should be orchestrating, so move the command up there. Since the parent also needs legitimate access to the Location, then just expose the Location as a property on your LocationVM? Surely anything using a LocationVM will want to know the location?

Comment: What if i only let the LocationVM expose the LocationId (i forgot about mentioning it) which is enough for the Map to get the actual Location object?

Comment: Loads of my VM's expose the models, the models are there to represent your data, so let people use them. You only need to keep them encapsulated if other code shouldn't know anything about them. A map clearly knows about and uses Locations. You could just expose the ID if you want, but there doesn't seem much point to me. If something has access to an ID, then surely it can go and fetch the corresponding model object if it wanted? Why not just give it the object?

Comment: Surely a good point. What about binding to parent VM from an ItemTemplate? FindAncestor is not available in WP8. Also, since the MapView is an user control i think that using ElementName will kill it's reusability, ain't it?

Comment: AH ignore the comment above i just realized how silly it is ;-)

Comment: You could pass the parent command to the childVM in its constructor, and the childVm simply exposes it if you wanted. Or even just pass in an action that the child calls when its command is called. The former is probably simpler though.

Comment: Yes i was thinking about this. I could even pass the MapVM to the LocationVM. After all it's ok for a location to know about the map it's part of. This discussion helped me a lot in cleaning my design so i'll mark your post as an answer. Thanks a lot.